# convert get to post http method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm doing simple restful api task and every thing is work fine. but i won't to convert something and i don't know how!

```
@RequestMapping("/user/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Users> getUserById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUserById(id));
}
```

i want to convert this get method to post method, so send the id in body then get the result. How can i do that? 
and can i do login like this way ?? check the email and password if it true then redirect to another page, or there is ways to do this in best another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the value and method properties for converting this into post.

```
@RequestMapping("/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Users> getUserById(@Param Integer id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUserById(id));
}
```

Comment: Remove `{id}` from path.

Comment: Did you mean `@RequestParam`?

Comment: yes its work with removed /{id} and replace @Param with RequestParam, Thx